# How to run a program for a limited time as a specified user without leaving a trace on the linux system?

Tags: linux, cleanup, resource-management

I have to run a non-trusted, third-party application on a linux server.

The program should be run as a specified user for a limited time, for example 30s.

During this period, the program can use all the system resources, but it can write only below a specified directory.

After the program terminates or is terminated because of the timeout, the system have to be cleaned, so it is in **exactly** the same state as before running the application.

There should not be any descriptors, sockets, spawned processes, files or other system resources left out.

How can I do that?

Comment: Stop hacking!!!

Comment: This seems more like a design/programming question to me.

Comment: It's not hacking, it's more like have the possibility to run a program every time in a "known, clean" environment, but without using virtualization.

Comment: It's not about programming, the program is not known. I have the system and the program, I have to start it and to have the system in the same state after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like an operating system container. The [Solaris Version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/containers-169727.html) used to be called a Zone, which is a kind of virtualization where multiple virtual machines share a kernel, but in effect have separate PID 0 processes, and even different file-systems.

If you really do need to run something that needs to execute and then reset everything back to a steady state, something like this would be a good choice. That our a snap-shotted full Virtual Machine; start the machine, run the process, stop the machine, roll-back to the known-good snapshot. Some, such as VMWare, can even do this process live, though there is a quite noticeable pause as it commits a live memory snapshot to disk (or recovers it from disk).

Comment: The concept with the virtual machine is perfect, this is exactly what I need as effect. But the problem is that I want this to be fast, the loading of the snapshot would be too slow. I am looking for a way to do that faster.

Comment: The other problem with virtualization is that the system is already virtualized, it is running on a VPS.

Comment: @HristoHristov It is quite possible to nest virtualization. Use something like OpenVZ to create a new container and do the deeds on a LVM array (perhaps based on loopback files) that gets un-snapped when the process finishes running.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new shell as a wrapper around the user shell.

When the user logs in, this shell creates a dynamic named ramdisk, chroots into it, spawns the concrete user shell, creates a new thread that sleeps 30 seconds, and after waiting it kills all child processes recursively, then destroys the ramdisk and logs out the user.

Programming this is left out as a homework.

Comment: The application needs the system files (other applications, libraries, etc.) so chroot-ing would be a problem. How to make sure all resources are free after termination? How to kill all child processes?

Comment: bad question? too localized? downvote, closing? and you answer **that**? thanks anyway